# In menu, 3rd level dropdown comes down to the 2nd level menu bug

Tags: jquery, css

As in opencart the 3rd level mobile can't be accessible so i did some changes and coding to the header.tpl every thing goes fine except the 3rd level menu in desktop version, when i hover the top menu the 3rd level comes down to the 2nd level men first time then it works as usual but every time i refresh same bug occurs

here is the screenshot and the link

**when i mouseover first time on components menu**

[image]

**when i mouseover on monitor**

[image]

**once i am i have mouseout from the monitor menu and again mouseover on components it shows fine**

[image]

the bug comes only first time load or refreshing of the page

for more view see this link

http://itracktraining.com/testoc/oc/upload/

new things i have added in the website

these three codes

http://itracktraining.com/testoc/oc/upload/catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/jquery.smartmenus.bootstrap.css

http://itracktraining.com/testoc/oc/upload/catalog/view/javascript/jquery.smartmenus.js

http://itracktraining.com/testoc/oc/upload/catalog/view/javascript/jquery.smartmenus.bootstrap.js

Answer (score 1):

Make the following changes:

**CSS:**

```
.dropdown-menu { top: 0;  left: 100%;}
ul.dropdown-menu li{position:relative}
```

Check and see it might work

Comment: by adding these lines i am getting another bug kindly check out over the http://itracktraining.com/testoc/oc/upload/ link